# export dynamic html string to PDF using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

I have a stringbuilder with html with tables and data,images from the database loaded.
Is there anyway that i can export html string directly to pdf using asp.net.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked for [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can export HTML string to PDF using iTextSharp.

Here's the code:

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

Protected Sub imgViewPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)
Using sw As New StringWriter()
    Using hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>")
        sb.Append("<head>")

        sb.Append("</head>")
        sb.Append("<body>")

        sb.Append("</body>")
        sb.Append("</html>")



        Dim sr As New StringReader(sb.ToString())

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportedClientDocument.pdf")
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 42F, 40F, 90F, 50F)
        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)

        Dim pdfWriter__1 As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
        pdfDoc.Open()

        htmlparser.Parse(sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()


        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
    End Using
End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul   , But i am not able to parse the images , od we need to have anyother parser to read the below image                        <tr><td><img src='D:\image\pdfimages\logo.png' border='0'/></td></tr>

Comment: @Ramesh You can try like this: <img src='"+Server.MapPath("image\pdfimages\logo.png")+"' border='0'/>